# How do I change where mod_mono logs its errors?

Tags: apache-2.2, asp.net, mono

I have set up mod_mono on Centos 5.4. It seems to be working, except that mono sends its log information (exception tracebacks) to the global apache error log. I'd like it to send these errors to the per-vhost logs. Is this possible?

Thanks